# CSS Selector with multiple class and one ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this structure

```
<body class="page-id-47745">
<head id="#masthead">
```

for multiple page and i need to select #masthead for this specific page based on ID:

```
.page-id-47745, .page-id-35419 #masthead {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
}
```

This code not work, only if write 1 Class:

```
.page-id-35419 #masthead {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
}
```

Why i have this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to select that specific masthead? Couldn't you just put a class to the one masthead you need to alter and use thta class?

Comment: Becasue i have different masthead based on pageid but the output for page is static i have only 1 reference page-id =)

Comment: Try with this `body.page-id-35419 #masthead {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
}`

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid You didn't understand the question bro. `:(`

Comment: why <body> and <head> doesn't have closing tag over there ?

Comment: It's an example =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `id` in both. Each one is a different selector:

```css
.page-id-47745 #masthead,
.page-id-35419 #masthead {
  padding-bottom: 40px !important;
}
```